# Entry Of Duplicate Rows in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates

Please I need your help with my script. I'm trying to insert values into `maintable`, but before I insert, I have to check if a row have an exact match compared to the one I'm inserting. If there's a match then it should `echo Record Exists`, and if not it should go ahead and insert into the table. The problem is that it is returning `0` for `$duplicate`, when actually there is a row that matches the entries that I've entered in the HTML page, thereby it goes ahead and inserts the duplicate.
Please what could the problem be?

```
{
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT m.matric_no, m.course_code, m semester_name, m.level, m.session 
                          FROM  maintable AS m 
                          WHERE m.matric_no = '".$matric_no."'
                          AND m.course_code = '".$course_code."'
                          AND m.semester_name = '". $semester_name."'
                          AND m.level = '".$level."'
                          AND m.session = '".$session."'") ;

    $duplicate = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($duplicate > 0 ) 
        echo "$duplicate" ;
    {
        echo "Record Exists"     
    }
    else
    {

        $query = "INSERT INTO maintable (matric_no, course_code, semester_nam,          session, level) 
                   VALUES ('".$matric_no."', 
                       '".$course_code."',
                       '".$semester_name."',
                       '".$session."', 
                       '".$level."')" ;
        mysql_query($query) or
            die (mysql_error());   

        echo"Record Inserted"; 
    }
```

Please forgive my formatting, I typed on a mobile, I didn't mean disrespect to this community.

Comment: Is the `{` before your `echo "$duplicate"` statement in your original code? Note that it is almost impossible to help if you cannot paste your original code here.

Comment: @jeroen yes it was -- this is what's causing the error IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formatting's a bit all over the place, which is why you're finding it so hard to spot errors when they occur.  Try sticking to a consistent format style.  This should do the trick:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE matric_no = '$matric_no' AND course_code = '$course_code' AND m.semester_name = '$semester_name' AND m.level = '$level' AND m.session = '$session'");

if(mysql_num_rows($check))
{
   echo 'Record exists!';
}
else
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO maintable (matric_no, course_code, semester_nam, session, level) VALUES ('$matric_no','$course_code','$semester_name','$session','$level')";
   mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie, it actually did do the trick, but in my query i (and previous ones), i normally pick the columns that i feel will be enough for checking the duplicates, and it has worked very well before, why do you think this didnt work. Thanks for the answer. It was spot on.

Answer (score 0):

You are counting rows, which may return `0` if no records matching your query were found. However you are mixing if code block

```
if ($duplicate > 0 ) 
    echo "$duplicate" ;
{
    echo "Record Exists"     
}
```

Should be

```
if ($duplicate > 0 )         
{
    echo "$duplicate" ;
    echo "Record Exists"     
}
```

I have checked your code, and it seems valid. Try to simplify it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM maintable WHERE matric_no = '$matric_no' AND course_code = '$course_code' AND m.semester_name = '$semester_name' AND m.level = '$level' AND m.session = '$session'");

if(!mysql_num_rows($result))
{
   $query = "INSERT INTO maintable (matric_no, course_code, semester_nam, session, level) VALUES ('$matric_no','$course_code','$semester_name','$session','$level')";
   mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Starx... The $duplicate was just to echo out the number of rows returned so that i'll be sure the query is processed. But the actual problem was the fact that you have used ' SELECT * ' , as supposed to selesting the individual columns that i felt was neccessary. It has worked for me this way in some other scripts. Why didnt it work here.
Thanks for the answer, i most appreciate it.

Comment: @dotman14, The problem is not selecting all columns or selecting a few. The problem probably occurred, as a mysql_error() which was not trapped by `mysql_num_rows() > 0`. So I used boolean expression just to be sure

Comment: thanks for the answer. Actually i did the ' SELECT * ' , from the answer you provided then used the if ($duplicates > 0), and it gave me the same result. What could make the mysql_now_rows() > 0 not trapped by mysql_error().?

Thanks for your help